# Why can't I access a ViewController variable inside of a function (Swift3)?

Tags: ios, swift

This is driving me insane. This should be the simplest thing in the world, and it is just not working, no matter what I try.

What I am trying to do is very simple. There is a text field and a button in my view. You enter an ID number in the text field, and hit the button. When you hit the button, it executes a web request, sending the ID number to a PHP script, which processes it, and returns a string. I only want to store the returned string to a variable, and send it via segue to a new view controller.

Here is my code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //================ Member Variables ================//
    var customerDetails: NSString = ""

    //================ Object Outlets ================//
    @IBOutlet weak var deviceID: UITextField!

    //================ Object Actions ================//
    @IBAction func checkDeviceID(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(deviceID.text!)
        validateDevice(deviceID: deviceID.text!)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let step2VC: Step2ViewController = segue.destination as! Step2ViewController
        step2VC.deviceID = deviceID.text!
        step2VC.customerDetails = customerDetails
    }

    //================ Custom Methods ================//
    func validateDevice(deviceID: String) {
        //Send a request out to server to validate credentials
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        guard let URL = URL(string: "http://monitt.dynamiscms.com/library/getCustomerDetails.php") else {return}
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let bodyObject: [String: String] = [
            "deviceID": deviceID
        ]

        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyObject, options: [])
        var responseString: NSString = ""

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if (error == nil) {
                // Success
                let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                print("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")

                responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
                self.customerDetails = responseString

                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
            else {
                // Failure
                print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupStep2", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

In my validateDevice function, where I have the print statement, it successfully displays the returned result from the PHP script. But, despite the fact that I pre-defined the variable outside of the functions, I still cannot seem to get the customerDetails variable to hold the returned results from the script.

Can anybody shed some insight as to what I am doing wrong?

A successful answer is one that allows me to set the contents of "customerDetails" to a text field in the next ViewController, and have it contain the contents from the web script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `self` and it looks like you are.

Are you waiting until after the network call has been completed before accessing (or passing) `customerDetails`?

Move the `performSegue(forIdentifier:sender:)` call to the inside of the network calls closure. The complier will warn you that you'll need to add `self`.

```
func validateDevice(deviceID: String) {

    //Send a request out to server to validate credentials

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    guard let URL = URL(string: "http://monitt.dynamiscms.com/library/getCustomerDetails.php") else {return}
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let bodyObject: [String: String] = [
        "deviceID": deviceID
    ]

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyObject, options: [])
    var responseString: NSString = ""

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            print("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")

            responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            self.customerDetails = responseString

            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupStep2", sender: nil)
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should performSegue after the network call is finished

```
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            print("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")

            responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            self.customerDetails = responseString
            //Here
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupStep2", sender: nil)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Besides, there is no need to call

```
 session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```